# downloading and installing ftdi(d2xx and vcp)drivers?

Tags: drivers, setup

I tried downloading the d2xx and vcp drivers to start working on vmusic3. But the link provided by FTDI site does not have the '.exe' file even after I extract the folder.Where do I download the required drivers?

Comment: Drivers may be provided either as a setup executable or as a compressed archive. In the latter case you just need to [install them manually](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-hardware-or-device-drivers-manually-in-windows-vista/). Either way, if you look carefully you will noticed the [official website](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) *does* provide an executable version (see the Comments column).

Comment: thank you.i got them.it was in the newest version which i happened to overlook somehow...thanks anyway! :-)